# Create Button is not showing up after following the Odoo Tutorial when creating a new module

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am in the process of learning to develop Odoo and started by following this tutorial *https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/06_firstui.html .* Currently I am stuck on chapter 6.

I created a estate_*menus.xml file and a estate_property*_views.xml file in the views folder. My code looks like that:

estate_*property*_views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="estate_property_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Properties</field>
        <field name="res_model">estate.property</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a new property
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>



#estate_menus.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <menuitem id="estate_menu_root" name="Real Estate">
        <menuitem id="estate_first_level_menu" name="Advertisements">
            <menuitem id="estate_menu_action" action="estate_property_action"/>
        </menuitem>
    </menuitem>
</odoo>
```

This is my manifest file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

{
    'name' : 'Estate',
    'application': True,
    'depends' : ['base'],

    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/estate_property_views.xml',
        'views/estate_menus.xml',
        
    ]

}
```

Everything looks fine except the Create button is missing and I have no idea why. Could you give me hint in which file I made a mistake? Thank you very much!

I tried the code above but the button is still missing.

Answer (score 4):

In Chapter 5, you have created the access rights for your model and as per tutorial

```
id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_test_model,access_test_model,model_test_model,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
```

You have given only read access to `base.group_user` so you can modify your `ir.model.access.csv` and you can give write and create and unlink access as below:

```
id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_test_model,access_test_model,model_test_model,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. For the moment, I solved it by unifying both files.
Also try creating the `estate_menus.xml` file with nothing inside, just:

```
<odoo></odoo>
```

and i have the same problem.

I'm still looking for the correct answer. Greetings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).